# assertThrows get error message and assert based on that

Tags: scala

I have a custom runtime exception:

```
case class AEMAuthenticationException(
  message: String
) extends RuntimeException(message)
```

while writing test, I am using AssertThrows:

```
assertThrows[AEMAuthenticationException] {
      AEMUtils.validateAEMRequest[AEMFragment](
        status =  401,
        resBody = resBody
      )
    }
```

the above succeeds, however there are multiple Authentication exception that I would like to test. And I have distinguished them based on error message.

So my question is how can I have error message and assert based on that?

Something like below:

```
assertThrows[AEMAuthenticationException] {error => {
      AEMUtils.validateAEMRequest[AEMFragment](
        status =  401,
        resBody = resBody
      )
      assert(error.getMessage === "Expired Credentials")
     }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [ScalaTest documentation](https://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_assertions) suggests `intercept` for examining a thrown exception:

```scala
val error = intercept[AEMAuthenticationException] {
      AEMUtils.validateAEMRequest[AEMFragment](
        status =  401,
        resBody = resBody
      )
    }
assert(error.getMessage === "Expired Credentials")
```

Comment: Hmm using `intercept` throws exception: `Expected exception AEMAuthenticationException to be thrown, but java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError was thrown
`
However assertThrows[AEMAuthenticationException] works fine

Comment: Ok my bad, I needed to do a `sbt clean` before running individual tests. Thanks!